# Codeigniter HMVC callback function not showing errors on ajax form validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i have a function with form validation with callback function and it works fine until i put ajax on it. the only problem is, it doesnt show the error if the error is from a callback function

here is my controller

```
public function create(){

    $data = array('success' => false, 'messages' => array());

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('DEPARTMENT','Department','trim|required|max_length[50]|callback_if_exist');

    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="text-danger"','</p>');

    if($this->form_validation->run($this)){

        $insert = $this->Department_Model->insert();
        $data['success'] = true;
    }else{
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            # code...
            $data['messages'][$key] = form_error($key);
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

/////////// CALLBACK

```
public function if_exist(){

    $available = $this->Department_Model->check_if_exist();

    if($available){
        return TRUE;
    }else{

        $this->form_validation->set_message('if_exist','{field} already exist!');
        return FALSE;

    }

}
```

Model

```
public function check_if_exist(){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->table WHERE DEPARTMENT = ?";
    $data = array('DEPARTMENT' => $this->input->post('DEPARTMENT'));

    $query = $this->db->query($sql, $data);

    if($query->num_rows() == 0){

        return TRUE;
    }else{

        return FALSE;
    }
```

and here is my java script

```
<script>
  $('#form-user').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var me = $(this);

    // perform ajax
    $.ajax({
      url: me.attr('action'),
      type: 'post',
      data: me.serialize(),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response) {
        if (response.success == true) {
          // if success we would show message
          // and also remove the error class
          $('#the-message').append('<div class="alert alert-success">' +
            '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>' +
            ' Data has been saved' +
            '</div>');
          $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error')
                  .removeClass('has-success');
          $('.text-danger').remove();

          // reset the form
          me[0].reset();

          // close the message after seconds
          $('.alert-success').delay(500).show(10, function() {
            $(this).delay(3000).hide(10, function() {
              $(this).remove();
            });
          })
        }
        else {
          $.each(response.messages, function(key, value) {
            var element = $('#' + key);

            element.closest('div.form-control')
            .removeClass('has-error')
            .addClass(value.length > 0 ? 'has-error' : '')
            .find('.text-danger')
            .remove();

            element.after(value);
          });
        }
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

it shows every single error except for the callback error

Comment: Post your $this->Department_Model->check_if_exist(); function

Comment: i didnt get it. i will add it to the question or is it the answer? @Gopal

Comment: model function check_if_exist(); ? please post here with above question

Comment: @Gopal i already updated this.

Comment: $this->input->post('DEPARTMENT') returns string or INT?

Comment: $this->input->post('DEPARTMENT') is a string. but what i return is boolean value.

Comment: Ok try execute query like this $query = $this->db->query(""SELECT * FROM $this->table WHERE DEPARTMENT = '$this->input->post('DEPARTMENT')'");

Comment: the problem is just that the error is not showing. everything else works fine. just the ajax showing the error of callback